# Proof that $V_{a}^{b}=\lim_{n \to \infty} V_{a}^{c_{n}}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} V_{c_{n}}^{c_{n+1}}$

Tags: real-analysis

I want to show that if $f$ is bounded variation and $\{c_{n} \}$ is a strictly increasing sequence on $[a, b]$ s.t. $c_{0}=a$ and $c_{n} \to b$ when $n \to \infty$ it follows that
$$V_{a}^{b}(f)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} V_{c_{n}}^{c_{n+1}}$$

As $c_{n} \to b$ when $n \to \infty$ then we can suppose
$$V_{a}^{b}(f)=\lim_{n \to \infty} V_{a}^{c_{n}} (f)$$

if $P$ is any partition of $[a, b]$ then $V_{a}^{b}(f)= \sup_{P} \{V_{P}(f) \}=\sup_{P} \{\sum_{k=1}^{n} |f(x_{k})-f(x_{k-1})| \}$ and note that if $P_{1}$ is a partition of $[a, b] \cup \{c_{n} \}$

$\lim_{n \to \infty} V_{a}^{c_{n}} (f)=\lim_{n \to \infty} \sup_{P_{1}} \{\sum_{k=1}^{n} |f(x_{k})-f(x_{k-1})| \}$

That is what is known, but from this I do not know how to deal with the demonstration. Any help is welcome!

Answer (score 1):

Let $f=1_{\{b\}}, c_n = 1-{1 \over n}$, then $V_{a}^{b}(f)= 1$, but $V_{c_{n}}^{c_{n+1}} = 0$ for all $n$, so the result is not true. All the variation occurs at the end point.